# Regex issue for match a column value

Tags: linux, awk

I wrote a script to extract a column  value from a file which doesn't matches the pattern defined in col metadata file.

But it is not returning the right output. Can anyone point out the issue here? I was trying to match string with double quotes .quotes also needs to be matched.

Code:

```
          `awk -F'|' -v n="$col_pos" -v m="$col_patt" 'NR!=1 && $n !~ "^" m "$" {
                     printf "%s:%s:%s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $0 > "/dev/stderr"
                     count++
                   }  
                   END {print count}' $input_file`
```

run output :-
++ awk '-F|' -v n=4 -v 'm="[a-z]+@gmail.com"' 'NR!=1 && $n !~ "^" m "$" {
printf "%s:%s:%s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $0 > "/dev/stderr"
count++
}
END {print count}' /test/data/infa_shared/dev/SrcFiles/datawarehouse/poc/BNX.csv

10,22,"00AF","abc@gmail.com",197,10,1/1/2020 12:06:10.260 PM,"BNX","Hard b","50","Us",1,"25" -- this line is not expected in output as it matches the email pattern "[a-z]+@gmail.com". pattern is extracted from the below file

Input file for pattern extraction file_col_metadata

FILE_ID~col_POS~COL_START_POS~COL_END_POS~datatype~delimited_ind~col_format~columnlength
5~4~~~char~Y~"[a-z]+@gmail.com"~100

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you show using a field separator of `'|'`, yet your input is comma delimited. Presumable `col_pos` can be a field number or REGEX assigned to the awk variable `n`, but then you proceed to use it as `$n` as if it were a shell variable. Further, using `!~ "^" m "$"` is not clear on what you are attempting to match. Please see if you can clarify.`

Comment: Is that line you don't want matched being matched?

Comment: Thank you changing the separator worked . I havn't noticed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace `awk -F'|' ...` with `awk -F',' ...` it will work.